# Validation not triggered on af:selectOneRadio component

Tags: javascript, validation, jsf, oracle-adf, selectoneradio

After some research I found out, that ADF has this bug with validating radio buttons on the page. The problem here is that the validation of the radio groups does not take place at the same time as the input text fields. First the input text fields are validated, then the radio groups. From what I've seen from ADF forums its listed as a bug.

The question is following, maybe someone figure out somekind of workaround for this? Is it possible in ADF 11.1.1.7.0 to trigger validation for all required text fields and radio buttons at the same time?

In https://community.oracle.com/thread/1033932 Frank Nimphius sad, that validation will work in case, if you use **unselectedLabel** property and this works for me. But then, additional button (representing unselectedLabel) appears  in my radiogroup. Is it possible to make it unvisible somehow leaving other selectItems visible?

P.S. Bug id is 13822582

Comment: have you tried using, `text=""  visible="false"` ?

Comment: visible="false" will hide all buttons including the one, which comes as unselectedLabel = "" removes text from the button, but button still visible and checked from defaults.